# How to modify an audio signal on the fly?

Tags: matlab, audio, dynamic, signal-processing

I'm currently programming an application which goal is to **generate audio sine waves such that frequencies increase or decrease over time**.
However the user should be able to **use up and down keys in order to counter this drift**.
For example : if the frequency is decreasing over time, the user should be able to press the up key to increase it dynamically.

The thing is I can't find any information on how to do such a thing. I've been using the `soundsc(audio, fs)` function which allows to play a sound at a given sample rate, but I always must create the sine wave before feeding it to the function which leaves no room for **dynamic variations**.

Is it possible to do this in Matlab ? If so, what function allows you to make this ? If there is no function for that, how should I proceed ?

Here is my current code if you want to take a look at it :

```
% soundTesting.m

fs = 16000;
s = generateWave(400, 1, fs, 5);
t = generateTarget(800, 1, fs, 5, 0.5);
audio = [s; t]';
% Playing audio in stereo with target audio on the right speaker and drifting sine wave on the left
% Note that for now the sine wave is not drifting at all.
soundsc(audio, fs);
```

```
%generateWave.m

function wave = generateWave(frequency, amplitude, fs, length)
    ts = 1 / fs;
    t = 0 : ts : length;
    wave = amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency * t);
end
```

```
%generateTarget.m

function target = generateTarget(frequency, amplitude, fs, length, span)
    wave = generateWave(frequency, amplitude, fs, length);
    target = zeros(size(wave));
    for i = 1 : length - 1
        % Every second, emit the target sound for span seconds.
        target(i * fs : i * fs + int32(span * fs)) = wave(i * fs : i * fs + int32(span * fs));
    end
end
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe listen for a keypress and if the up/down key is pressed, create a new audio, stop the current audio and play the new one? Not sure it'll sound smooth though, but it's worth a shot

Comment: Yes that's a solution I will be exploring indeed, thank you very much. :)
But perhaps there is a simpler/more built-in way, so if anyone knows about it, I'd be really thankful !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of buffered audio output, so that you can pass a block of samples into the buffer and they will be fed to the output by a separate task with the right timing.

If your licence includes the Audio Toolbox, have a look at the Mathworks page [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/audio/gs/audio-io-buffering-latency-and-throughput.html). If not you could try [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28394-jaudio-buffered-sound-class?s_tid=srchtitle) from the MATLAB file exchange.